# Return a value or assigning a value to a variable and then return - best practice?

Tags: python, software-design

Suppose I have two functions

```py
def sum(a, b):
    result = a + b
    return result
```

and

```py
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b
```

From the point of view of good programming practices and software engineering, which solution is better? Return a value or assigning a value to a variable and then return? Why?

Comment: 2nd option is better as it minimizes code bloating

Comment: 2nd option as you are not initialising a variable which is not being used in any logic, saving small amount of memory and also making code small and simpler.

Comment: the compiler will translate the first option into the second, so just use the second

Comment: With a name like `result` there's no point at all. It's only worth doing if the name provides information that's not available from e.g. the name of the function and the expression that produces it.

Comment: @YusefMaali no, not in CPython it won't.

Comment: In any case, performance considerations here are practically irrelevant. Readability and style considerations are the issue here. I agree with @jonrsharpe that a name could be useful if it were descriptive in an effort to write self-documenting code. But with just result? I would simply return. In any case, this is too-opinion based

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i didn't know the cpython compiler is so simple. I just read here: https://nullprogram.com/blog/2019/02/24/

Comment: @YusefMaali yes, as that blogpost states "The general rule of thumb is to simply not expect much from these bytecode compilers. ". Although note, most of those optimizations are actually not as important in a language like Python, that is high-level and these things would sae you relatively small time. Also, CPython objects are all allocated on a privately managed heap, where further optimizations occur that make allocating small, common types of objects like `list` and `tuple` quite efficient.

Answer (score 1):

2nd option is good because it saves space of a variable but at times, we use more variables on purpose for the sake of clarity. We always have to maintain a good balance between clarity and space.

Comment: The space savings are practically irrelevant.

Comment: Will(instructor) from FrontEndMasters says and I quoted above :) @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @MuhammadNaufil if there's a quote provide appropriate formatting and references.

Comment: Who from where?

Comment: I mean, quite frankly, why should anyone care? And I suspect this is in the context of a JS, where you want to minimize the size of the source code for websites (almost always an irrelevant consideration for the sorts of things Python is used for). In any case, the best practice would be to write your code *clearly* then pass it through a minifier if you are worried abut file-size.